# array unique and merge value in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, unique

I have one big array and I want to make it unique on doc_id and merge roleid

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test ÆØÅ
            [doc_id] => 279
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  76, 276
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test ÆØÅ
            [doc_id] => 279
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  76, 276
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => NVD AS
            [doc_id] => 415
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => NVD AS
            [doc_id] => 415
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  76, 276
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test for SN
            [doc_id] => 506
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  76, 276
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test for SN
            [doc_id] => 506
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  6
        )
```

Just to make it unique I am using below code

```
foreach ($arry as $val) {
            $newArr[$arry ->doc_id] = $val;
        }
        $result = array_values($newArr);
```

I am able to get unique document but I lost roleid, I need to merge roleid with doc_id
it should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test ÆØÅ
            [doc_id] => 279
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  76, 276
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => NVD AS
            [doc_id] => 415
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] =>  2,76, 276
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Test for SN
            [doc_id] => 506
            [mid] => 
            [type] => 3
            [label] => 
            [roleid] => 6,76, 276
        )
Can anyone help in this
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The above is not a multidimensional array but an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current format of `roleid` is not in the best format for processing. If you change it to array you can do something similar to this:

```
$item1 = new stdClass();
$item1->doc_id = 279;
$item1->role_id = '76, 276, 3';

$item2 = new stdClass();
$item2->doc_id = 279;
$item2->role_id = '1, 44, 76';

$item3 = new stdClass();
$item3->doc_id = 279;
$item3->role_id = '8, 44, 1';

$data = [$item1, $item2, $item3];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (isset($result[$item->doc_id])) {
        $existingIds = explode(', ', $result[$item->doc_id]->role_id);
        $newIds = explode(', ', $item->role_id);

        $result[$item->doc_id]->role_id = implode(', ', array_unique(array_merge(
            $existingIds,
            $newIds
        )));

        continue;
    }

    $result[$item->doc_id] = $item;
}


print_r($result);
```

With the result:

```
Array
(
    [279] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc_id] => 279
            [role_id] => 76, 276, 3, 1, 44, 8
        )

)
```

Comment: But I am getting this roleid in the query as comma separated values. How can I change it

Comment: You can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions to change the string into array before array merge and back to string after.

Comment: I tired to explode role like this but then I got array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array                                                                         $roleid = explode(',', $item->roleid);
    $result[$item->doc_id]->roleid = array_merge(
     $result[$item->doc_id]->roleid,
     $roleid
    );

Comment: Thanks, now its merging but make some strange result. like [roleid] =>  191, 231, 245,  191, 231, 245,  191, 231, 245,  191, 245,  191, 245,  231

Comment: merged value more than one time

Comment: You can get unique values with [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Put this function in front of `array_merge` similar to this: `array_unique(array_merge(..., ...))`. It should help

Comment: array_unique make it unique but then don't merge values :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115295/discussion-between-lukas-hajdu-and-new-php-developer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try merging your arrays using the `array_merge_recursive()` function.

```
$mergedArray = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

#### Edit

You are losing values because you overwrite them. You should use two loops.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
        $newArray[$value->doc_id][$subkey] = $subvalue;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a reason why the above wouldn't work for you. Though I'll write you another solution:

```
$newaArray = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!is_array($newArray[$value->doc_id])) {
        $newArray[$value->doc_id] = array();
    }
    $newArray[$value->doc_id] = array_merge($newArray[$value->doc_id], $value);
}
```

#### Resources

- [array_merge_recursive() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: if I use array_merge_recursive() then I will lose unique array;

Comment: `not work` is difficult for me to do something with. What happens if you use my foreach?

Comment: It same array wit unique values but roleids are not merged